# Rigid Body Unbalanced Weights

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I have not seen a post about this on BSE yet.
Is there a way to create a rigid body simulation with two connected objects with different weights?
Think of a hammer or a mace. Naturally, the heaviest part (usually the metal head) would fall facing the ground, with the lighter part facing up.

However, rigid body physics simulates an object as one single weight without any heavier or lighter parts.
Using compound rigid body physics with child and parent relationships would not solve the problem because they are meant mainly for individual not necessarily connected objects, and they do not allow for each individual object to have a different weight.

Is there any way to simulate a rigid body object with varying weights throughout the object accurately?

Comment: Torque doesn't exist in rigid body physics-- they're a very limited simulation.  All of the mass is located in a single point.  But, you can move the center of mass.  The center of mass in Blender's rigid body sim is at the origin of the object.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a rigid body constraint:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/rigid_body/constraints
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/rigid_body/constraints/types/fixed.html